# MATLAB to Julia RGB image conversion

Tags: image, matlab, julia

I am working with RGB, 2D images.

In MATLAB I can do something like

```
imread(img, "file.png")
# access img(2, 4, 1) for the red color channel
# access img(2, 4, 2) for the green color channel
```

In Julia I want to do something similar...

```
load("file.png", img)
# access img[2, 4, 1] will not work
```

I know this is because of how images are encoded in Julia. But is there a way to convert these matrices in Julia to match the format used in MATLAB?

I apologize in advance for being a Julia newbie, and couldn't find any docs for this

Comment: I presume you mean `img = imread("file.png")` and `img = load("file.png")`?

Comment: I do -- sorry! Wrote that code off the top of my head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [FileIO](https://github.com/JuliaIO/FileIO.jl) and [Colors](https://github.com/JuliaGraphics/Colors.jl) packages for this:

```
using FileIO, Colors
# load png
img = FileIO.load("file.png")
# access each channel with any of the following access patterns
green.(img)
red(img[begin, end-3])
blue.(img[1:4, 5:7])
```

If your PNG has transparency, you could access alpha by the function `alpha` similarly to the red, green and blue functions above.